# toggling booleans in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean, toggle

I am pretty new in javascript and there seems to be something I just don't get about booleans. I am trying to toggle a boolean whenever someone clicks on an element on my webpage. The code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var toggled;
$("#button").click(function(){
   toggled=!toggled;
}); 
if(toggled){
     $(".offcanvas").css("margin-left","0%");
}
else{
    $(".offcanvas").css("margin-left","-40%");
}
```

});

If someone could explain me what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to the async nature of JS. The boolean is being toggled in the callback on each click, but it's only being checked once when the code is read initially. It doesn't listen for changes to that variable, so your margins aren't being changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toggled = false;
  $("#button").click(function(){
   toggled=!toggled;
    if(toggled){
       $(".offcanvas").css("margin-left","0%");
    }
    else{
      $(".offcanvas").css("margin-left","-40%");
    }
  });
});
```

Moving the if structure inside the click event will ensure it is checked after the toggle is changed.  Setting a default value just feels right to me, although with truthy/falsy you might be good there.